# Filter first ten minutes of pcap

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, editcap

I have a large pcap file, and I would like to generate a new pcap that contains only the first ten minutes of traffic. Can I do this with `tcpdump`? I have seen `editcap` mentioned online, but I would like to use `tcpdump` if possible.

Comment: Try using [`wireshark`](https://www.wireshark.org) or it's command line equivalent `tshark`. You can use it to open a pcap and export a selection or range of packets.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html); however, it would be much simpler with [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) because the only practical way to do this with `tcpdump` that I can think of is to use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html) (or [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)) to first find the frame number of the packet that is at least 10 minutes into the capture file.  Once you have the frame number, `tcpdump` can be used to only save packets up until that frame, effectively limiting the output file to the desired 10 minute duration.  Here's how:

First, find the first packet that is at least 10 minutes into the capture file (here I'll illustrate with `tshark`, but Wireshark could be used as well):

```
tshark -r bigfile.pcap -Y "frame.time_relative <= 600.0"
```

Note the frame number of the last packet displayed.  (The frame number is the first number of each row, assuming standard `tshark` columns.)  For illustrative purposes, let's say it's frame number 21038.

Second, use `tcpdump` to only save the first 21038 frames to a new file:

```
tcpdump -r bigfile.pcap -c 21038 -w bigfile_first10min.pcap
```

But since `editcap` comes with the Wireshark suite, you could much more simply accomplish the equivalent by using the following, which will split up the large capture file into capture files each of 10 minutes in duration (except the last one, which might be less):

```
editcap -F pcap -i 600 bigfile.pcap bigfile_split10min.pcap
```

If you're only interested in the first file, then disregard the rest of them.

Of course as noted by @madmax1, you could also apply a simple modification to the above `tshark` command to write the packets matching the filter to a new file:

```
tshark -r bigfile.pcap -Y "frame.time_relative <= 600.0" -w bigfile_first10min.pcap
```